# Парсинг websocket python

Tags: python, websocket

у меня есть ссылка на сайт:

- wss://stream295.forexpros.com/echo/479/huv_c91t/websocket
- wss://stream198.forexpros.com/echo/465/8zo98wk6/websocket

как через python с парсить данные из этих сокетов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно подключиться к сокету (например используя библиотеку websockets для python) и прослушивать сообщения, которые будут приходить, а их уже, в свою очередь парсить.

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765" # url вебсокета
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send("Hello world!") # отправка сообщения
        await websocket.recv() # получение сообщения

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Код из официальной документации websockets

Comment: А не понадобится ли что-то еще для подключения к `wss`? У вас в примере `ws`

Comment: зависит от сокета, но это понять можно только изучив, как конкретный сокет действует. А вобще, вам же не нужно что то еще, чтобы послать реквест на https, а то в примерах http). Проще говоря дело в том, что wss(как и https) шифрованное соединение, ws(http) нет

Comment: Можно посмотреть что выводит данная функция?

Comment: @Буднипрограммиста https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ тут есть два примера, один для сервера, другой для клиента, можете запустить и посмотреть. А данные, которые вам будут приходить и прочее будет зависить от того, как написан сервер, а не от того, как написана ваша часть. Для этого можете так же использовать websockets из aiohttp